# How to include the jquery library code in codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

My Dropdown menu,

```
   <select  id="type" name="name" onchange="getval(this);">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Two</option>
    </select>
    <select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
    </select>
```

My javascript code,

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/code/asset/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>//i want to include js file

 <script type="text/javascript">
function getval(sel) {
    var val = sel.value;
    if (val == 1) {
        $("#size").html("<option value='1'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>");
    } else if (val == 2) {
        $("#size").html("<option value='2'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>");

    } else if (val == 3) {
        $("#size").html("<option value='3'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");

    }

}
```

Path for jquery file

```
  C:\xampp\htdocs\code\asset\js\jquery-1.10.2.js
```

Is there any mistake in including jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js i used this code in my jquery-1.9.1.js file

Comment: Didnot understand your comment above actually you need to include the JQuery library only once in a page. Add the above line in your header section and dont include any other version of JQuery in the page again. @darshan

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('code/asset/js/jquery-1.9.1.js')?>"></script>
```

Or to use directly from the jQuery site use the following

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Use following

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'code/asset/js/jquery-1.9.1.js'; ?>"></script>
```